# Why doesn't mongrel start in Rails 3.2.rc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

GEMFILE that starts mongrel

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'mongrel', '>=1.2.0.pre2'
```

GEMFILE that start WEBrick (not mongrel)

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'
gem 'mongrel', '>=1.2.0.pre2'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Starting on Rails 3.2 you must specify the server you want to use, otherwise Webrick will be used.

So, to use mongrel, you must place the gem at your Gemfile AND start the server like this:

```
$ rails s mongrel
```