# Rails s doesn't boot mongrel by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm developing rails app on

```
Mac OSX 10.7
RVM
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.2.0
```

But, when I run **rails s**, Webrick will be booted by default.

**Note that**

- I can boot into Mongrel by **rails s mongrel**. But as I start and stop the server for like every few minutes, it will be great if I can avoid typing 8 extra characters. And yes, I can do linux command to run specific previous command (something like !200). But, I'd be glad to solve this problem
- This project used to develop with Rails 311rc2 and Ruby 1.9.3 (By previous developer) but with a lot of problems. So, I decided to switch to Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.0
- I need to use Ruby 1.8.7 as it's the same version as my company production server and all other projects/developers are using 1.8.7 too

I've been looking for a solution for almost two hours, visit a lot of site, tried all suggestion I found. But, none of them works

Here's my gem file

```
group :development do
    gem 'mongrel', '>= 1.2.0.pre2'
    gem 'ruby-debug'
end
```

What I tried,

```
1. uninstall and reinstall rvm 1.8.7
2. remove and reinstall gemset
3. remove all gem and run bundle install
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853338/why-doesnt-mongrel-start-in-rails-3-2-rc

Comment: By that you mean, no way to run "rails s" and boot Mongrel by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not rails related but Rack related.

Before, rack by default launch a mongrel server if you have mongrel install. Now, this behavior change in prior of Thin. So if you have thin install, rack launch it instead of webrick.

If you want allways launch by Mongrel. specify it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm appreciate your answer. It's kinda answer I was looking for : )

Comment: FWIW: "specify it" means `rails s mongrel`